# SQL Server Triggers: Update

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

Using Microsoft SQL Server, I am writing a SQL trigger for an update on a table and I am stuck. I am not very proficient in SQL, so it may be something basic that I am missing.

```
CREATE TRIGGER test
ON  tableName
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @variableA int
SELECT @variableA = variableA FROM DELETED

DECLARE @variableB int
SELECT @variableB = variableB FROM INSERTED;

f(@variableA <> @variableB )
BEGIN
//Do What I want
END
```

This works correctly, as it preforms the action when the two variables are different. However, I do not want to consider ALL records from tableName.

I wrote the following to get only the entries that I want.

```
WITH
table (variableID, variable)
AS
(
    SELECT variableID, variable
    FROM tableName
    WHERE variable= 'value'
)

SELECT * FROM table
```

So what I want is to apply the trigger ONLY to the values that are found in the SELECT. Am I going about this the right way?

Comment: Is `variableID` the primary key of `tableName`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `UPDATE` query isn't guaranteed to only impact a single row at a time, and your queries against `INSERTED` and `DELETED` need to reflect that to be on the safe side. Probably the easiest way to detect a changed value is to join the two trigger tables on the primary key.

```
CREATE TRIGGER test ON tableName
AFTER UPDATE AS 
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM INSERTED I
      INNER JOIN DELETED D ON I.variableID = D.variableID
      WHERE D.VariableA <> I.VariableB
        /* AND further conditions */
  ) BEGIN
    -- Perform your action
  END
END
```

Where this snippet has `/* AND further conditions */` would be a good place to insert the additional checks you want to do against the data before running your action.

For example, you can limit your action to updates where `variable` was `'value'` *before the update...*

```
AND D.variable = 'value'
```

or where `variable` is set to `'value'` *by the update...*

```
AND I.variable = 'value'
```

Comment: Thank you this is great, however what if my WITH statement didn't only contain a simple WHERE but also contained multiple joins? How can I include that?

Comment: `AND D.variableID IN ( SELECT variableID FROM /* whatever your with statement actually was */ )` or you can add the join conditions to the SELECT on inserted and deleted.